# dokku-alt postgres superuser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, dokku, dokku-alt

I am trying to use dokku-alt (https://github.com/dokku-alt/dokku-alt) to provision a VPS for a Rails App (Ruby 2.1.3, Rails 4.1.2), but my app uses a Postgres extension (pg_trgm).

Unfortunately dokku-alt doesn't currently support the admin_console command, as opposed to here: https://github.com/jeffutter/dokku-postgresql-plugin

Does anyone know of a way to get into the postgres console using the root or postgres user given that Docker is being used?

Comment: We would appreciate it if you would accept the answer or else comment on how/why it failed?  It helps others reading these questions to know if the answer worked or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can do it like so:

```
docker ps
```

That should give you a list of containers and their ID's, find the one that is running your postgres instance (could be one for all apps, might be one for each other app)

```
docker run <container_name> psql
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using even close the latest version of dokku-alt, there is a admin console command.

I recently ran into a problem where I had to grant super user access to one of our apps.

What I did was

`dokku postgresql:console:admin <<EOF
ALTER USER dbusername WITH SUPERUSER;
EOF`

Running `dokku postgresql:console:admin` should give you direct access into the main psql console.